# How to take a screenshot of a HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm working on a project that's basically a web form that the user fills in. Once complete they can save a screenshot of the entire, complete form to use as a sort of pamphlet.

I'm trying to work out the best way to approach this programatically.

I have a simple prototype working using the `canvas` tag, but the text formatting options aren't good enough for what I need so I'm wondering if there's some other way to generate a screenshot of a HTML element.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Maybe you can accomplish the same thing in another way. I don't think that what you are trying to accomplish is possible.

Comment: SVG may be an option if you want to do it in-browser

Comment: For rendering html into pdf [wkhtmltopdf command tool](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) is best. Practically it renders the page using webkit engine and creates PDF for you. That means you can even use @font-face, scripts, etc. You can find some docs [here](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I may suggest, post the result to a webserver and create a nice PDF document from it using some reporting tool available.

In my opinion, this is the best, maintainable solution. No need for hacking it in HTML or Javascript. You can use your own logo, print layout, fonts, etc.

Comment: This is a good solution, but I would mention that any user drawings on the html5 canvas will not be persisted to the server unless you serialize the canvas content by "hacking it in javascript" (serialize==save/replay all canvas drawing commands or save the canvas dataURL). ;-)

Comment: @markE: OP has a form which can be easily posted. He tried to solve it with a `canvas`. I think this is a case of the XY problem.

Comment: @markE: No problem. Thanks for giving your thoughts on the subject.